# Is there a workaround to run Android Emulator inside a VPN?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, vpn

I have my Android Studio installed on a VPN and when I am trying to run my emulator inside VPN it doesnot show up. I understand emulator is itself a virtual machine and virtual machine cant run inside another virtual machine, is there a workaround for this.

Comment: I don't think, that it's possible. I had the same issue and I had to move to another machine without virtual machine to get the emulator running

Comment: yea even i was thinking the same but was curious to know if there is a workaround, I do a contract job and I had to work on companys VPN now there is no way I can run emulator on VPN and company doesnot let me work on their machine, I am trapped.

Comment: one way is to connect through usb and run your app on phone but in my case due to security reasons accessing through USB is disabled too on VPN.